# WebScrape This Field

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes into a webpage, and identifies each block in the page.

Each block contains the same style format for information.

When trying to get the title however, I am not able to pull anything?

Ideally i want the Title, Abstract, And Author.

Here is my code so far in trying it for the title, using xpath.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?filters=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')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='ng-star-inserted')
for item in productlist:
    title=item.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']").text
    print(title)
```

Comment: Post a relevant snippet of the HTML from driver.page_source. Clicking on random links is very risky.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Snippet of the website has been posted

Comment: Using the wrong div class.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan hm, what would be the right one ?

Comment: //div[@class='record']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and let me know if you have any query -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get(
    'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?filters=JTVCJTdCJTIyZmllbGQlMjIlM0ElMjJmY3RNZWV0aW5nTmFtZSUyMiUyQyUyMnZhbH'
    'VlJTIyJTNBJTIyQVNDTyUyMEFubnVhbCUyME1lZXRpbmclMjIlMkMlMjJxdWVyeVZhbHVlJTIyJTNBJTIyQVNDTyUyMEFubnVhbCUyME1lZXRpbmclM'
    'jIlMkMlMjJjaGlsZHJlbiUyMiUzQSU1QiU1RCUyQyUyMmluZGV4JTIyJTNBMCUyQyUyMm5lc3RlZFBhdGglMjIlM0ElMjIwJTIyJTdEJTJDJTdCJTIy'
    'ZmllbGQlMjIlM0ElMjJZZWFyJTIyJTJDJTIydmFsdWUlMjIlM0ElMjIyMDIxJTIyJTJDJTIycXVlcnlWYWx1ZSUyMiUzQSUyMjIwMjElMjIlMkMlMjJ'
    'jaGlsZHJlbiUyMiUzQSU1QiU1RCUyQyUyMmluZGV4JTIyJTNBMSUyQyUyMm5lc3RlZFBhdGglMjIlM0ElMjIxJTIyJTdEJTVE')

AllRecords = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class=\"record\"]")))

for SingleRecord in AllRecords:
    print("Title :- " + SingleRecord.find_element_by_xpath(
        "./descendant::div[contains(@class,\"record__title\")]/span").text)
    print("Author :- " + SingleRecord.find_element_by_xpath(
        "./descendant::div[contains(text(),\"Author\")]/following-sibling::div").text)
    print("Abstract :- " + SingleRecord.find_element_by_xpath(
        "./descendant::span[contains(text(),\"Abstract\")]/parent::div/following-sibling::span").text)
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
```

The Output looks like -
[image]
if it resolves then please mark it as answer.

Comment: how to also get the session?

Comment: use this `xpath` for session - `//div[@class="record"]/descendant::div[contains(@class,"record__meta__title")]/following-sibling::div[contains(text(),"Session")]`

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
driver.get('https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?filters=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')
productList=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='record']")))
for product in productList:
    title=product.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']").text
    print(title)
```

Use .// and wait for the elements to be present. Also the div class you used was off.

Outputs

```
A post-COVID survey of current and future parents among faculty, trainees, and research staff at an...
Novel approach to improve the diagnosis of pediatric cancer in Kenya via telehealth education.
Sexual harassment of oncologists.
Overall survival with circulating tumor DNA-guided therapy in advanced non-small cell lung cancer.
```

The other two are

```
.//div[@class='record__ellipsis']
.//span[.=' Abstract ']/following::span
```

Comment: ah, thank you. what benefit does .// have over //

Comment: .// is from the parent root it grabs the first xpath in that html element . // grabs from the first in the entire html.